# Spring @Scope("request") does not work with Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, spring, scope, servlet-3.0

I am trying to use a request scoped been inside my servlet 3.0 application.

I am not using the web.xml but an implementation of WebApplicationInitializer. The onStartup method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext =
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    applicationContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    applicationContext.scan("package containing proxy scoped bean and other stuff");

    applicationContext.refresh();        

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}
```

and the request scoped bean looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class CallerInformation {

    private String clientIp;

    public String getClientIp() {
        return clientIp;
    }

    public void setClientIp(String clientIp) {
        this.clientIp = clientIp;
    }
}
```

Now the injected "CallerInformation" is not a CGLIB-proxy but behaves like prototype scoped, it is a different instance in every class and it does not hold any information through the request...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have tried the same scenario with servlet 2.5 and web.xml config and it worked like hell ;)

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried it with servlet 3.0 and web.xml?  try it also...

Comment: Also try to change the order as `servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener()); servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));` Listerner orders can also do some problems . Not 100% sure thats the cause here..
    `

Comment: Why using proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS ? if you use proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES it will fix your problem, it fixed the problem to me in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724716/problems-with-bean-declared-as-scope-request-in-servlet-3-0-configuration

Answer (score 0):

the behavior is right.
the instance only lives the one request.
see [this site](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) for further information.

try to inject the spring-component with the [@Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem: Inside of ONE request there are n different instances of CallerInformation, each with own (in my case null) property values.

Comment: ah okay i understand. 
have you tried checking if there are multiple request instance?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. The CallerInformaion instance should be some kind of CGLIB-proxy, but it isn't. I think Spring does not evaluate the @Scope or somthink...

Comment: how do you autowire it? constructor, setter, or field?

Comment: with the @Inject annotation

Comment: @Autowired did not help. The problem is not, that there is no bean injected, the problem is that the bean is not request scoped.